# Meteor: Detect if token has expired before submission?

Tags: meteor

I am building a reset password screen in Meteor and I would like to detect if the reset password token has expired BEFORE I ask the user to fill out the form (password + confirm password) and click the submit button. It just seems like better UX.

However, I can't seem to find any methods or helpers in the Meteor docs that allow you to pass in a token and check to see if it's still valid or not. The only thing I can find is an error message that the token is expired AFTER the user submits. Which could be annoying to the customer, to have taken the time to fill out the form when we knew from the start that it wouldn't work. They would then have to go and get a new link, and re-fill out the form.

Is there not a better way to do this in Meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy to check if a token is still valid.

You can do something in the lines of:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  checkResetToken(token) {
    check(token, String);

    const user = Meteor.users.findOne({
      "services.password.reset.token": token});
    if (!user) { // never existed or already been used
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Token expired");
    }

    const when = user.services.password.reset.when;
    const reason = user.services.password.reset.reason;
    let tokenLifetimeMs = Accounts._getPasswordResetTokenLifetimeMs();
    if (reason === "enroll") {
      tokenLifetimeMs = Accounts._getPasswordEnrollTokenLifetimeMs();
    }
    const currentTimeMs = Date.now();
    if ((currentTimeMs - when) > tokenLifetimeMs) { // timeout
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Token expired");
    }

    // you can return some of the user's details to further improve the UX.
  }
});
```

adapted from the code of the `accounts-password` package.

Then, use it in your client-side hook in order to determine whether the token is still valid and perhaps get some of the user's details from the server (e.g, whether it is an enrollment token or the user's name/email) to display a more personalized view.

Note that the `user` includes all of the secret fields, so don't return all of it to the client.